# AngularJs unable to check cacheId already exists

Tags: angularjs

I have a requirement where I need to store local settings of user into some cache object. I tried to implement this using `$cacheFactory` e.g.

`var userCache = $cacheFactory('users');`

However, when my code hit this line again, it gives me following error:

> **Error** : cacheId 'users' is already taken !

I am not sure, how to check if this ID is already exists, because I need to fetch settings from this cache object on each time component loads.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually listed how to do this on [the documentation page:](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory)

The `$cacheFactory()` function is not a "get or create" call, it's only a create.

This is how you would check if the cache has already been created:

```
if (!$cacheFactory.get('users')) {
  var userCache = $cacheFactory('users');
}
```

which can be changed to

```
var userCache = $cacheFactory.get('users') || $cacheFactory('users');
```